# Pandas get unique monthly data based on date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like the following dataframe:

```
d=pd.DataFrame()
d['id']=['a','a','a','b','b','c']
d['version_start']=['2017-01-01','2017-02-12','2017-03-25','2017-01-01','2017-6-15','2017-01-22']
d['version_end']=['2017-02-11','2017-03-24','2017-08-01','2017-06-14','2018-01-01','2018-01-01']
d['version_start']=pd.to_datetime(d.version_start)
d['version_end']=pd.to_datetime(d.version_end)
d['values']=[10,15,20,5,6,200]
print d
  id version_start version_end  values
0  a    2017-01-01  2017-02-11      10
1  a    2017-02-12  2017-03-24      15
2  a    2017-03-25  2017-08-01      20
3  b    2017-01-01  2017-06-14       5
4  b    2017-06-15  2018-01-01       6
5  c    2017-01-22  2018-01-01     200
```

The version start and version end represent for each ID, the date range for which that row can be considered valid. For example, the total values for a given date would be the records for which that date is between the version start and version end.

I am looking to get for a set of dates (the first of the month for each month in 2017) the sum of the "values" field. I can do this by looping through each month as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for month in pd.date_range('2017-01-01','2018-01-01',freq='MS'):
    s = d[(d.version_start<=month)&(d.version_end>month)]
    s['month']=month
    s=s.set_index(['month','id'])[['values']]
    df=df.append(s)    

print df.groupby(level='month')['values'].sum()

2017-01-01     15
2017-02-01    215
2017-03-01    220
2017-04-01    225
2017-05-01    225
2017-06-01    225
2017-07-01    226
2017-08-01    206
2017-09-01    206
2017-10-01    206
2017-11-01    206
2017-12-01    206
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

Is there a more elegant / efficient solution that doesn't require looping through this list of dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
d.version_start=d.version_start+ pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)
d.version_end=d.version_end+ pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)
d['New']=d[['version_start','version_end']].apply(lambda x : pd.date_range(start=x.version_start,end=x.version_end,freq='MS').tolist(),1)
d.set_index(['id','version_start','version_end','values']).New.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index('values').groupby(0)['values'].sum()



Out[845]: 
0
2017-01-01     15
2017-02-01    215
2017-03-01    230
2017-04-01    240
2017-05-01    225
2017-06-01    225
2017-07-01    231
2017-08-01    226
2017-09-01    206
2017-10-01    206
2017-11-01    206
2017-12-01    206
2018-01-01    206
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep thinking there should be a *way* more elegant way to do this, but for now:

```
s = pd.Series(0, index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01','2018-01-01',freq='MS'))
for _id, start, end, values in d.itertuples(index=False):
    s[start:end] += values
```

this returns the proper series, and works with any series for that matter.

If you want `version_end` day to be *excluded*, a quick fix is to add this line before the for cycle (only works if you are using `'MS'` as frequency):

```
d.version_end = d.version_end.apply(lambda t: t.replace(day=2))
```

I think the idea of using explicit indexing is cleaner than conditional indexing based on comparisons between dates, which at scale is terribly slow (`timestamps` are a valid alternative if you are forced to do this on huge arrays).